# jQuery | display geocomplete and datepicker value

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with two issues:

the first jsfiddle: http://goo.gl/OUgNAO 
after picking a date there should appear the text in "#datepicker_target". if i type in text manually and choose then to pick a date, it suddenly works. but it should obviously do it automatically.

the second jsfiddle: http://goo.gl/LrcQp7
the same mechanics. the picked address appears in the "#target" how it should. but after deleting the input, "Start:" keeps visible. How can i avoid this?

I would really appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first issue:

```
    $("#datepicker").on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            $("#datepicker_target").show().html('Date: <br>' +' <b>' +  $('#datepicker').val()) + '<b>';
        } else {
            $("#datepicker_target").hide();
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CLnYq/4/

For second issue:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#geocompletestart').change(function(){
            $('#target').html('<b>' + $('#geocompletestart').val()) + '<b>';
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EcPdP/19/